# Less than half of medical procedures are based on adequate evidence. What percent of those should we expect to be wrong?

Tags: p-value, biostatistics, observational-study

["The proportion of medical procedures unsupported by evidence may be nearly half."](https://www.vox.com/the-big-idea/2017/12/28/16823266/medical-treatments-evidence-based-expensive-cost-stents)

If we assume that half of all procedures are based on observational data, what methods can we use to estimate how many are bad procedures?

Could we assume a power of 50%, and say that for a p-value of 0.05 only .5*1.96 or .98% of unsupported procedures can be expected to work. Which means ~99% of the half are bad?

Is there any way of making an estimate?

Comment: No. You cannot do that kind of calculation. A p-value only has a weak connection to the probability that as intervention works (in the sense that if you study a plausibly effective intervention and get a low-p-value based on a lot off information, it is probable the intervention works). But p-values from superiority tests are very bad for figuring out what does not work.

Comment: Is there any way of making an estimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that half of procedures are unsupported by evidence, and hence not known to be good, doesn't imply anything about how good those procedures are.

As an analogy, suppose that a man has flipped 1,000 coins and told you for 500 of those whether each came up heads or tails. For the remaining 500, he tells you only that he didn't check. So who knows how many of the 500 came up heads? The case of medical procedures is actually worse, because in the case of coins we know that the base rate of getting heads is 50%, but we have no idea what the base rate of medical procedures being clinically useful is. (You might be tempted to estimate this rate by looking at the rate among procedures that *have* been studied, but the probability of a procedure being studied is unlikely to be independent of the probability of being clinically useful.)

[image: [Two people are about to enter a bed for.. activities.] Person 1: "Don't worry - I've been tested." Person 2: ...and you're clean? Person 1: "So many questions!"]

([xkcd #1096](https://xkcd.com/1096) by Randall Munroe, 2012)

Comment: Couldn't you bootstrap from the 500 heads/tails distribution and make a guess about the next 500?

Comment: @user2801011 This is the line of thinking I address in the last sentence (except that there's no need for bootstrapping because you're estimating the parameter of a Bernoulli distribution, and there's a simple formula for that).